# What is the best one-line way to clone array passed by reference in Perl?

Tags: perl, clone, argument-passing

When passing array to sub by reference, i need to clone the array, because i don't want reflect local array changes out of sub, so i can do this:

```
$arrayref = shift;
$arrayref = [ map { $_ } @$arrayref ];
```

Is there a better, elegant one-line way of doing this? Please take a note about passing array by reference and assigning reference to new array to the same variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map { $_ }` is redundant.  Just do:

```
$arrayref = [ @$arrayref ];
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the map statement. Simply de-reference your arrayref with the `@` sigil, create a new anonymous arrayref using the de-referenced values, then assign the result of that to some new variable.

```
main::(-e:1):   0
  DB<1> $a = [1,2,3];

  DB<2> x $a;
0  ARRAY(0x7fe7cb80bd78)
   0  1
   1  2
   2  3
  DB<3> $b = [ @$a ];

  DB<4> x $b;
0  ARRAY(0x7fe7cc0b9da0)  # < different address
   0  1
   1  2
   2  3
```

You could also wrap this in a simple sub:

```
sub clone {
   my $arrayref = shift; 

   croak 'Supplied argument is not an arrayref'
      unless $arrayref && ref($arrayref) eq 'ARRAY';

   return [ @$arrayref ];
}
```

Note: if your data-structure has more than 1-layer (e.g. multi-dimensional arrays) this solution will not work, because the inner references will remain the same. There is a nice module called [`Clone`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Clone) on CPAN that can handle nested data-structures quite well.

Answer (score 2):

You can do everything in one command:

```
my $clonedref = [ @{ shift() } ];
```

Note it only clones the top layer of the array reference, i.e. if there are structures nested in the array, they won't be cloned.